# Usando varios contextos en EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Tengo una aplicación asp.net core y utilizo dos contextos definidos así:

```
public class Contex1 : DbContext
{

    public  DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public  DbSet<Universidad> Universidades { get; set; }
    public  DbSet<Ciudad> Ciudades { get; set;}
    public  DbSet<UsuariosRegistrados> UsuariosRegistrados { get; set; }                  


}
public class Usuario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public Universidad Universidad { get; set; }
}

public class Universidad
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public Ciudad Ciudad { get; set; }

}

public class Ciudad
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

}

public class Contex2 : DbContext
{

    public  DbSet<RegistroCamaraComercio>RegistroCamaraComercio { get; set; }
    public  DbSet<TipoSangre> TipoSangre { get; set; }

}

public class RegistroCamaraComercio
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public  Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
    public  TipoSangre TipoSangre { get; set; }

}   

public class TipoSangre
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }


}
```

La cuestión es que como pueden ver la entidad RegistroCamaraComercio del contexto2 tiene una propiedad Usuario del contexto1, entonces cuando deseo realizar un insert de un nuevo registro del tipo RegistroCamaraComercio, yo rescato la entidad usuario utilizando el contexto1, pero cuando realizo el savechanges() utilizando el contexto2 , este me arroja una excepcion la cual es **"No se puede insertar un valor explícito en la columna de Id de la tabla 'Usuario' cuando IDENTITY_INSERT es OFF."**, despues de haber realizado varios intentos y ver que en la consola, esto sucede debido a que el esta tratando de insertar un nuevo Usuario y no el rescatar el ya existente , esto lo solucioné agregando la propiedad Usuario a un Dbset del contexto2 asi:

```
public  DbSet<RegistroCamaraComercio> RegistroCamaraComercio { get; set; }
    public  DbSet<TipoSangre> TipoSangre { get; set; }
    public  DbSet<Usuario>Usuarios { get; set; }
```

y ya desde el contexto2 consulto mi Usuario y lo agrego al nuevo registro de mi entidad RegistroCamaraComercio.

Mi pregunta es:
¿Existe alguna forma de poder hacer el insert de RegistroCamaraComercio  rescando el usuario desde el contexto1 pero haciendo el savechanges()desde el contexto2? , debido a que esta tecnica que utilizo  es poco util , y me tocaria replicar todas en las entidades en los contextos.

Ante todo muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: A partir de EF 6 se puede usar el mismo modelo para varios contextos, pero aun no entiendo los dos modelos se definen igual en los diferentes contextos?, cuando insertas en una tabla puedes obtener el id generado y cargar el nuevo registro, este ultimo salvarlo en el segundo contexto. como estas guardando?

Answer (score 1):

Cada contexto mapear la entidad a la misma tabla pero el ambito sera separado, puedes tener la misma entidad, en este caso `Usuario` en dos contexto, pero cada uno mapea su propia entidad como lo necesite, no puedes cruzarlos

Si lo haces debes recordar que deberas agregar la instancia para que resuelva el estado.

Una entidad que recuperas en un context sera tomada como `desconectada` por el otro ya que no puede seguir el `tracking`

[Working with Disconnected Entity Graph in Entity Framework Core](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-disconnected-entity-graph-ef-core.aspx)

Vas a tener que realizar un `attach` y definie el estado

```
context2.Attach(usuario).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

entonces si podras asociarlo a la entidad `RegistroCamaraComercio`

Pero lo que recomendaria es que busques directamente el usuario en el `contexto2` ya que alli tambien lo tienes mapeado, solo que no lo expones como propiedad

```
public class Contex2 : DbContext
{
    public  DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

    public  DbSet<RegistroCamaraComercio>RegistroCamaraComercio { get; set; }
    public  DbSet<TipoSangre> TipoSangre { get; set; }

}
```

mapea ese `Usuario` a la misma tabla que usa el `contexto1`, asi podras realizar la query desde ambos contextos